# No data received error with Joomla 1.5.25

Tags: php, apache, joomla, centos

I'm getting "No Data Received. Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data." error randomly when I restart my httpd server.

Whenever this happens, I need to restart the server again.

Why does this happen at all?

Is this something to do with Joomla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely an error on the server end. Ensure that you are running a fairly up to date version of PHP and MySQL. Also, just incase there is a problem your end, try connecting to the website from a different internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem, and disabling memcache stops the problem from happening on my local machine. Sorry I can't help any more than that.